# aapt.exe has stopped working error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Eclipse Kepler (eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64) on Windows 7.

My Eclipse is installed in D:\Dev\Eclipse
My workspace is: E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight
Java installation: D:\Dev\Java (version 1.7)

I have installed the latest Android SDK (R24) in D:\Dev\AndroidSDK
I have also installed the latest Android SDK Tools (R24.02) and Android 5.0.1 APIs..

I have created AVD 5.0.1.

Problem:

I have created a HelloWorld program, ran it successfully on the mobilefirst server.
I then built the Android environment, which created a HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid project.

But when I tried to run the HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid project as Android application, I am getting the following error message:

> aapt.ext has stopped working A problem caused the program to stop
>   working correctly. Please close the program.

I have read through other postings and verified the following:

- Went through
  D:\Dev\AndroidSDK\tools\apps\SdkController\res\layout\main.xml file
  and checked that all the @string values match the parameters in
  D:\Dev\AndroidSDK\tools\apps\SdkController\res\values\strings.xml
- Tried commenting out `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header in the main.xml

None of these made any difference.

I have updated my preference to verbose mode and saw the following console output messages  (everything else seems to be fine on the output). Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
 [2014-12-18 16:32:16 - HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-hdpi\settings.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-ldpi-v11\push.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-ldpi\settings.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-mdpi-v11\push.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-mdpi\settings.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-xhdpi-v11\push.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-xhdpi\push.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable-xhdpi\settings.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable\icon.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited [2014-12-18 16:32:16 -
 HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid]
 E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight\HelloWorklightProject\apps\HelloWorklight\android\native\res\drawable\push.png:
 libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
 edited
```

Comment: What are the details of the AVD you have created? Does it fail in a device as well or only in the Emulator. This is not Workight-related.

Comment: AVD Device Nexus One (3.7", 480 x 800: hdpi)
Target : Andorid 5.0.1 - API Level 21 
CPU/ABI : ARMS (armeabi-v7a)
Hardware keyboard present is checked
Skin:  Skin with dynamic hardware controls
Front and Back Camera : None
Memory Options: RAM 512, VM Heap: 32
Internal Storage : 200 MiB
SD Card : Size is checked but blank on MiB 
Emulation Options : Snapshot and Use Host GPU are not checked.

Comment: The applications runs fine on the MobileFirst console.  It fails on the Emulator, however.    I am getting the Application Error Message : net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (File://android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)

Same Error message on the phone.

Comment: I have updated my AVD Device to Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19.  (Everything else is same as the spec that i mentioned for level 21.  With Level 21, I started getting compile error on the HelloWorklightProjectHelloWorklightAndroid Project and couldn't even launch.   When I have installed V19 SDK tools and Android 4.4.2, and downgraded my AVD to Level19, it compiled... but still encountered error with the emulator and the phone

Comment: upload your generated android project to dropbox so i could try and run it

Comment: Sure.   I have uploaded the file to my dropbox.  How can I share the file with you?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3yxkjvxmg408t5q/android.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully ran your generated Android project in an Android 5.0.1 AVD.

After importing it to Eclipse:

1. In AndroidManifest.xml, changed `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` to `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`
2. Right-clicked the generated Android project > Properties > Android > selected "Android 5.0.1" from the Project Build Target list

My AVD setup:

[image]